# ListLinePlot in Version 13.3.0 causes the kernel to stop

Tags: plotting, kernel

**Bug introduced in 13.3.0 or earlier and persisting through 13.3.1 or later**

I have upgraded to version 13.3.0.  I find that when I plot a data set using `ListLinePlot` or `ListPlot` Mathematica aborts the kernel or just disappears.

I have opened a new session and typed the following about 10 times and generally it will go wrong when I move the cursor into the plot. There is no particular condition I have identified. Sometimes it does not go wrong immediately but only after  I start a new notebook and copy and run the same code into that notebook. I am wondering if anybody else can replicate this problem.

The initial code I type is

```
$Version

 (* Out[1]= "13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

f = 3.456;
sr = 2000;
data = Table[{t, 5.0 Sin[2 \[Pi] f t]}, {t, 0, 5 - 1/sr, 1/sr}];
Length@data

(* 10000 *)
```

At this stage there is no problem. When I start the following then I get the problem.

```
ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image]

I clicked around in this plot just now and it dropped the kernel again. I reran the code and clicked again and again the kernel was dropped.

Sometimes a pink box appears in the plot and then disappears.

Does anyone else see this problem?

Comment: MMA 13.3.0 Windows 10 I can not reproduce this bug.

Comment: No problems for me (13.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 3, 2023))

Comment: Have you tried reducing the amount of memory required for your plot by varying the parameter sr? Try reducing it to something like 1000 and see if the problem persists. Exceeding available RAM is a common reason for having the kernel quit on you.

Comment: Does the same bad behavior for me on 13.3.1 Windows 10.

Comment: @jdp This is a small file for me when signal processing. I often have several much larger files open.

Comment: @jdp The OP only has 10K points in the example, even a very basic laptop capable of running W10 should handle that, right?

Comment: Please verify whether `ListLinePlot[data, PlotHighlighting -> None]` fixes the issue.  Then please [report the issue to Wolfram](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/?topic=feedback).

Comment: @JasonB. Seems more robust but will continue to check. You may have found the issue. Thanks.  I have already reported to Wolfram.

Comment: @JasonB. I seem to have solved the issue using your suggestion of setting `PlotHighlighting -> None`. Thanks. Let's hope Wolfram can resolve the issue.

Comment: Confirmed bug from Wolfram CASE:5072329 bug in 13.3.0 and 13.3.1.