# Dynamic updating plot bug in version 13.3.1.0

Tags: plotting, visualization

I am using Mathematica 13.3.1.0. version on MacBook M2 and there are some issues with dynamic updating. When I disable it I get a strange grey square in the center of the plot. [image]

When I enable it It disappears but I have annoying plot highlighting which slows down my other parts of the code if I accidentally touch the curve with the cursor.  [image]

Is there some way to get rid of the grey square or disable plot highlighting in the settings?

Comment: Use the option `PlotHighlighting -> None`

Comment: but is there a way to do it for all plots in settings so that I didn’t type it everytime I plot something?

Comment: Please don't use the `bugs` tag when asking a question.  As per the `bugs` wiki: "This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions. Please use the standard bugs header instead of version tags in conjunction with this tag."

Comment: Put `SetOptions[Plot, PlotHighlighting -> None] ` in an [`init.m`] (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) file

Comment: This looks like the same bug as I reported to Wolfram see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/289598/12558])

Comment: Bob Hanlon's fix works. You have to put it in all the plotting methods e.g. `ListPlot` , `ListLinePlot` , `ListLogPlot` etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set

```
Charting`$InteractiveHighlighting = False;
```

Subsequent plots will be generated without the interactive highlighting. You can put the line in init.m if you want the change to be permanent. Or you can put it in an initialization cell in a notebook; note that when it is executed, it turns off the highlighting for the ***kernel*** session (unless it gets reset to `` Charting`$InteractiveHighlighting = True ``).